# Show custom post type relationships by taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, custom-field, permalinks

I have two custom post types `product` and `review`.
The `product` have a custom taxonomy `fruits` with terms `apples` and `bananas`.

All `review` has a custom field that is a relationship to `product`, so I can easily choose the product to review (using ACF). For example I might add a review post called "Granny Smith Review" and choose the product "Granny Smith".

In my navbar I have a link called 'Reviews' that points to this url: `example.com/review` and my `archive-review.php` successfully list all reviews.

**Question:**
Is it possible to have a url that points to `example.com/review/fruits/apples` or `example.com/review/apples` so I can have a dropdown menu called 'Apples' that only shows `review` with `apple` term (which is the taxonomy on the `product`)?

Or if you know any more clever way to structure things I would be glad to hear! Because it feels like I will have a lot of duplicate posts. But what is important is that I have the slug `review/fruits/apples` or `review/apples`.

I'm a new developer so I would be very happy with any feedback, thanks!:)

Comment: anyone? :) i'm really stuck on this...